# Why 'Key' is a reserved word in Transact-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

A lot of developers use Key as primary key name, but why Transact-SQL consider it as reserved word?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

And, the use of 'Key' as primary key name is an anti-pattern?

Comment: *"A lot of developers use Key as primary key name"* - Do they? Never seen it. Usually I see ID, or a more specific name like FooBarID.

Comment: It's used in T-SQL to define keys, that's why it's reserved.  If you want to use it as a column name, you most likely have to wrap it in brackets, like so: [Key]

Comment: Why wouldn't it be a reserved word?   It has a specific meaning in TSQL, like "TABLE" or "SELECT".   How could it not be a reserved word?

Comment: When I see the generic "ID" as the primary key for a table I know I am in for a long and painful future. That is a good indication that column names change depending on the table they are in. This is just painful to work with. In general, a name in a database should be well thought out and provide some insight into its usage. The word "key" by itself is totally ambiguous. Now if you change that to ProductKey or something relevant it is immediately perfectly clear what that is and the name can stay constant in any table throughout the entire system.

Comment: I prefer to use the table's name as a prefix to all it's columns. i.e for `tblProduct` the column name I would choose for the primary key would be `Product_Id`. That way you never have to deal with keywords. on the other hand, there are some built in functions (like `user_id`) that use the same naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEY` is a reserved word in the ANSI SQL standard (at least from SQL-92, probably since the earliest version) which would be a good reason for T-SQL to also treat it as reserved.

Source is the BNF Grammar maintained [here](http://savage.net.au/SQL/).

As for the question of whether using `KEY` as a primary key name is an anti-pattern or not, I would say that it is, just as using other reserved words would be. This is of course just an opinion (and convention in my experience) and the standard allows the use of reserved words as identifiers through the `delimited identifier` mechanism.

On a side note I don't think I've ever seen anyone use `key` as a column name.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand why you single out the reserved keyword `KEY` here. Would you ask the same question about `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, or `GROUP`? If so, why do you find it surprising that these words are reserved keywords? (Ever tried to call a variable `if` in any programming language?) If not, why not?

Like the keywords just mentioned, `KEY` is simply another (partial) keyword used e.g. to define a `PRIMARY KEY` or `FOREIGN KEY` constraint; that's a fairly common thing to do, not some rare corner case.

If you want to call your keys `KEY` (which seems quite unusual to me, never seen that done before), then escape it by putting it in square brackets: `[KEY]`.